# Button para ir al inicio de la pantalla del RecyclerView

Tags: android

Quiero tener un botón para que el usuario, si ha hecho Scroll, pueda presionar y volver al inicio de la pantalla, es decir, al primer item.

Problemas:

1. El Button aparece debajo del RecyclerView
2. Al hacer clic en el Button, no pasa nada

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!-- Este es -->
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/arrowUpImageView"
            style="@style/AppTheme.FilterIcon"
            android:layout_above="@id/addFab"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:clickable="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_arrow_up_grey_24dp" />

        <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
            android:id="@+id/addFab"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_margin="@dimen/fab_margin"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:backgroundTint="@color/progressBarColor"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/ic_add_white_24dp" />

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/postsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

Código:

```
public class HomeActivity extends AppCompatActivity
        implements ViewStub.OnClickListener {


    private ImageView mArrowUpImageView;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_home);

        mArrowUpImageView = findViewById(R.id.arrowUpImageView);
        mArrowUpImageView.setOnClickListener(this);

        // ScrollListener
        mRecyclerView.addOnScrollListener(new RecyclerView.OnScrollListener() {

            @Override
            public void onScrolled(RecyclerView recyclerView, int dx, int dy) {
                super.onScrolled(recyclerView, dx, dy);

                int visibility = mLinearLayoutManager.findFirstCompletelyVisibleItemPosition();
                if (visibility != 0) {
                    mArrowUpImageView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                } else {
                    mArrowUpImageView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                }
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        if (v == mArrowUpImageView) {
            // No funciona
            mLinearLayoutManager.scrollToPositionWithOffset(0,0);
        } 
    }
}
```

La idea es que cuando el usuario haya hecho Scroll hacia abajo un poco, haciendo clic en el botón pueda volver al inicio de la pantalla rápidamente. El botón debería de aparecer arriba del `FloatingActionButton`.

Alguna idea?.

Comment: Tu codigo funcionaba bien, solo tenias que mover de posicion, primeramente seria el `RecyclerView` -> `ImageView` -> `FloatingActionButton`

Comment: @A.Palacio Un usuario me sugirió mover de posición los componentes (ver respuestas debajo) pero, no me funcionó. Al final otro usuario me ha recomendado agregar otro `FloatingActionButton` más y ha quedado perfecto.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

puedes poner 2 FloatingButton, uno de ellos con visibility GONE para que cuando llegues al final, se cambie a VISIBLE aparezca:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".activity.HomeActivity">

<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout 
    android:id="@+id/swipeRefreshLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/postsRecyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:scrollbars="vertical" />

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>



    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_up"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="@dimen/fab_margin"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/ic_menu_add" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab_add"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom|end"
        android:layout_marginBottom="70dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/fab_margin"
        app:srcCompat="@android:drawable/arrow_up_float" />


</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Para que haga el Srooll utiliza:

```
fabUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                postsRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(1);
            }
        });
```

Comment: He probado tu solución y funciona, gracias amigo!. Lo único que he eliminado el `CoordinatorLayout`. He dejado todo igual a como yo lo tenía y solamente he agregado otro `FloatingActionButton` debajo y funciona correctamente. No sabía que se podía agregar varios `FloatingActionButton` con `drawable` diferente. Gracias por tu ayuda. Por cierto, por qué usas `CoordinatorLayout`, alguna razón para esto? a lo mejor me estoy perdiendo de algo aquí...

Comment: No, ninguna. para el scroll fabUp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                postsRecyclerView.smoothScrollToPosition(1);
            }
        });

Comment: Mira la respuesta rectificada

Comment: No hay de que, un saludo. :)